# Im getting a 0 byte image when grabbing a frame from the webcam

Tags: python, opencv, debian

I'm trying to make an app that takes images periodically.

So to start it off I thought I could make a app that takes a image and saves it. It saves it allright, but the image is empty... why is this?

```
import cv

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)

foo = cv.SaveImage("foo.jpg", img)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would advise you to test if `CaptureFromCAM()` succeeded by checking the value of capture.
You may also display the flow in a window.
Second, you will read in the [documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=saveimage#cv.SaveImage) that there are restrictions using `SaveImage()`.